# Measure space sum conclusions

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose $(X,S,\mu)$ is a measure space. Suppose $f_n$ is integrable for each $n$.

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int |f_n|d\mu<\infty$.

Then, $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \int |f_n|d\mu=\lim_N \int \sum_{n=1}^N |f_n| d\mu<\infty$. Hence, setting $g_N= \sum_{n=1}^N|f_n|$ for each $N$, we obtain a non-negative increasing sequence:

$g_1\leq g_2\leq g_3.....$, where each $g_N$ is integrable.

So by Fatou's lemma,

$\int \lim_n \inf \sum_{n=1}^N|f_n| d\mu\leq lim_N \inf  \int g_N d\mu =\lim \inf \int \sum_{n=1}^N |f_n| d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int |f_n|d\mu$.

I'm not sure sure what else can I conclude, may I have some help?

Comment: I think the point of the exercise is to show you can interchange countable sums with the integral, which is what you've shown

Comment: @Duncan i've been told that we can say something about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ is that true?

Comment: The integral of that quantity exists, so it must converge to a measurable function that is finite a.e.

Comment: How did you reason that out? @Duncan

Comment: By your proof, you have that $\lim \inf \int \sum_{n=1}^N |f_n| d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int |f_n|d\mu$. $\int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_nd\mu \leq \int \sum_{n=1} |f_n|d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int |f_n|d\mu < \infty$. So it must be finite a.e. and the following integral must exist $\int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_nd\mu $

Comment: @Duncan In general, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int f_n d\mu$ is finite then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges almost everywhere and $\int \sum f_n d\mu$ exists?

Comment: Yes that is true

Comment: @Duncan i'm having a hard time proving it, could you write a proof down, please? (for the "in general" claim"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $(f_n)$ is a sequence of non-negative integrable functions with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int f_n < \infty$. You can apply the MCT to $g_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} f_n $ with $g = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ to see that this integrable and that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges to a finite a.e. function. 
For a general function if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int | f_n| < \infty$ then you can use the DCT to demonstrate that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  f_n $ converges (note if this condition does not hold then the series does not converge). Is it clear now?

Comment: why does $g$ exist?

Comment: This follows by the monotone convergence theorem:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral

Comment: To expand, $g$ is the pointwise limit of $g_n$ and all $g_n$ are integrable so we can apply the MCT (monotone convergence theorem) to see that $g_n$ converges to $g$ and that the integral exists. The second is a similar argument but with the DCT (dominated convergence theorem). Note that your proof above implies this, too, I'm just trying to show another way that might be a bit more direct.

Comment: oh right, I had issues with seeing why the limit exists... but I recalled that we're working with the extended real numbers, so any increasing sequence is bounded and thus converges. Okay, everything is clear now. Thanks

Comment: last question, does the series converge everywhere? if not, I don't see why it converges almost everywhere

Comment: If I define some sequence $f_n$ such that we have the series converging everywhere except at some single point $x_0$, where I define $f_n(x_0) = (-1)^{n}$ then $\sum f_n(x_0)$ does not converge but $\sum f_n$ does converge everywhere else.